# AdMob ads stop display after checked on Primarily Child-Directed and Opt in to Designed for Families

Tags: admob

I was wondering one of my android app won't display ads anymore after I checked on Primarily Child-Directed and Opt in to Designed for Families in Google Play Console, anyone have idea about this matter?

Best Regards,
Virak

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question which should be asked of the Customer Service department for the company you are dealing with. Please see: [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746) and [Why we're not customer support for \[your favorite company\]](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the last 2 years (from 2015 to 2017) AdMob has had very low fill rate for DFF-compliant, child-directed requests (by "very low" I mean <2% which is basically zero), that's why you don't see any ads. If you check logcat you will see an "Ads: no fill" message.

Google is working on it but can't really do much, because it's advertizers who don't opt in to show their ads to children. Advertizers explicitly don't want to show ads to kids because kids mostly generate useless, random clicks.

If you choose DFF "mixed audience" though, you will get normal ads from AdMob, with 99% fill. However, if your app is really child-directed, starting from July 10, 2017 you will have to declare that in your app's listing, and then you have to participate in DFF, but aren't allowed to set "mixed audience". A person from Google told me to change ad network to something else (not AdMob) or at least add more networks as backfill/mediated. Check Kidoz and SuperAwesome - these won't offer eCPMs (or even fill rate) comparable to AdMob but if your app is child-targeted, there isn't anything else you can do at the moment. Btw Kidoz doesn't have banners, and last time I checked SuperAwesome's banners didn't work.

Btw if you app is DFF with an age designation (not "mixed audience") it will only show house ads for your other apps if they are also in DFF with an age designation (not "mixed audience"). So, unless all your apps are in DFF with an age designation, you can't even show house ads as backfill.

Just don't develop child-directed apps. This niche is only going to get worse.

Comment: I found also this one - http://www.adbuddiz.com/developers - they have ads content filtering system with 4 options , everyone is suitable for toddlers according to the site.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to make any code change. Admob will take care if app is specifically designed for child-directed Apps. For mixed audience App you need to make a small code change.

Please refer to this link https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6223431?hl=en

Primarily child-directed apps are apps that target "Ages 5 & Under", "Ages 6 to 8", and/or "Ages 9 to 12" in the Designed for Families program. **Once your app is admitted to the program under one of these age targets, AdMob will automatically begin serving Designed for Families-compliant ads for all ad requests coming from the app.**